# Tables missing when I convert Rmarkdown document with latex tables to docx

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, docx, pandoc

I have a document that contains a lot of `LaTeX` tables. I am trying to convert it to DocX so that I can share it with others. When I convert the document to DocX, the tables are missing. Has anyone been successful in being able to do this?

Here is an example to reproduce my issue.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_notebook: default
header-includes:
 - usepackage{longtable}
---

This is an [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) Notebook. When you execute code within the notebook, the results appear beneath the code.

Try executing this chunk by clicking the *Run* button within the chunk or by placing your cursor inside it and pressing *Cmd+Shift+Enter*.

```{r}
plot(cars)
```

Add a new chunk by clicking the *Insert Chunk* button on the toolbar or by pressing *Cmd+Option+I*.

When you save the notebook, an HTML file containing the code and output will be saved alongside it (click the *Preview* button or press *Cmd+Shift+K* to preview the HTML file).

The preview shows you a rendered HTML copy of the contents of the editor. Consequently, unlike *Knit*, *Preview* does not run any R code chunks. Instead, the output of the chunk when it was last run in the editor is displayed.
````

The table.Rmd document contains the following:

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
header-includes:
 - usepackage{longtable}
---

\begin{longtable}{ p{12cm} r }
Statement & XXX \\
\hline

line 1 & 100\% \\
line 2 & 100\% \\
line 3 & 88\% \\

\end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Latex user. But I think you may have a very small, but important syntax error in your YAML header, you have:

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
header-includes:
 - usepackage{longtable}
---
```

But the [Rmarkdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-logo.html) shows latex `header-includes:` as having **TWO** spaces indentation, which I think is important in terms of YAML, not sure if that is the root cause of your latex tables not rendering, but something I noticed.

```
---
title: Adding a Logo to LaTeX Title
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
---
```

However, I may be able to offer an alternative solution. Rmarkdown plays very nicely with Tables and HTML and allows for dynamic output. using the YAML option `always_allow_html: true` allows for a nice HTML type table rendered inside your Word document that looks very professional and aesthetically appealing, with only 3 lines of code. Hopefully it wouldn't be too much work to convert your `Latex` tables to. Although this may not be an exact answer for you, it is another way to generate tables in Rmarkdown into Word .Docx files.

````
---
title: "R notebook"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
output: word_document
always_allow_html: true
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
mtcars %>% 
  knit_print()
```
````

[image]